# Android doesn`t send data on first buttonpress

Tags: android, bluetooth

I`m attempting to send data through Bluetooth to another Bluetooth enabled device. This is using the SPP profile, and I based the app around the BluetoothChat sample code that is included with the SDK.

I changed the code so that if you press a button, the app automatically starts sending data through Bluetooth. There is also a stop button to stop sending data.

The problem is, when you first open the app and press the start button, it doesn`t send any data. If you press the start button again, it will work correctly and send data. Now there is no issue and all the buttons and sending data work fine.

But why would the very first time you press the start button fail? Here`s the relevant code.

Button listener

```
 mConversationView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Toast.makeText(BluetoothChat.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent serverIntent = null;
             switch (position) {
                case 2: //Connect button
                    serverIntent = new Intent(BluetoothChat.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
                    break;
                case 0: //Start button
                    sends = 1;
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(BluetoothChat.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
                    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                    break;
                case 1: //Stop button
                    sendMessage("F0.0\r\n");
                    sendMessage("G0.0\r\n");
                    sends = 0;
                    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(BluetoothChat.this);
                    break;
             };
        }
    });
```

OnSensorChanged event

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "acce", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if ((event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) || (sends==0))
        return;
    float mSensorX = 0;
    float mSensorY = 0;

    switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
        mSensorX = event.values[1];
        mSensorY = -event.values[0];
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
        mSensorX = -event.values[0];
        mSensorY = -event.values[1];
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        mSensorX = -event.values[1];
        mSensorY = event.values[0];
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        mSensorX = event.values[0];
        mSensorY = event.values[1];
        break;
}
    //if(mSensorX < 0)
        //mSensorX = mSensorX*-1;
    mSensorX = mSensorX * 3;
    float sendL;
    float sendR;
    mSensorY = mSensorY * (float)0.75;
    if(mSensorX < 1 && mSensorX > -3){
        mSensorX = 0;
    }
    if(mSensorY < 0){   //tilting right
        mSensorY = mSensorY*-1;
        if(mSensorX > -3){
            sendL = mSensorX + mSensorY;
            sendR = mSensorX - mSensorY;
        }
        else{
            sendL = mSensorX - mSensorY;
            sendR = mSensorX + mSensorY;
        }
    }
    else{               //tilting left
        if(mSensorX > -3){
            sendL = mSensorX - mSensorY;
            sendR = mSensorX + mSensorY;
        }
        else{
            sendL = mSensorX + mSensorY;
            sendR = mSensorX - mSensorY;
        }
    }
    String lll = "F";
    String rrr = "G";
    if(sendL < 0){
        lll = "V";
        sendL *= -1;
    }
    if(sendR < 0){
        rrr = "B";
        sendR *= -1;
    }

    String message = Float.toString(sendL);
    message = lll+message + "\r\n";
    sendMessage(message);
    message = Float.toString(sendR);
    message = rrr+message + "\r\n";
    sendMessage(message);

    //float mSensorY = event.values[1];
}
```

When you press the start button, it sets a flag and starts the listener. The stop button clears the flag and stops the listener. But I cant seem to figure out why it doesnt work on the first buttonpress. Thanks!

Comment: Your "Button listener" is an `AdapterView`'s item click listener?

Comment: Sorry, they are not actual buttons, but images in a grid that I basically treat as buttons. When you click on the image, the onClick event fires.

Comment: You didn't post the code where you actually open the connection sockets.

Comment: Here`s the paste: http://pastebin.com/1LbBSU9t (BluetoothChatservice.java)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my button listener:

```
case 0: //Start button
    sends = 1;
    mSensorManager.registerListener(BluetoothChat.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    break;
```

It only works after the first click because the mAcceleromter wasn`t initialized on the first click. To fix this, I just swapped those two lines.

```
case 0: //Start button
    sends = 1;
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(BluetoothChat.this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    break;
```

Now it works on the first button press.

Comment: @Ritesh Gune that requires a 2 day waiting period